# What is the correspondence between primary decomposition and algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

What is the correspondence between primary decomposition and algebraic geometry?

Comment: Try here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113865/geometric-meaning-of-primary-decomposition?rq=1

Comment: It is useful! Thank you!